# ERRORS Inserting a new theorem

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}



\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{easylist}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{showidx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{syntonly}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}

\begin{document}




 \part{TEORIA}

 \begin{theorem}
 Si a, b i c $=0$
 \end{theorem}
 \part{PROBLEMES} 
 \end{document}
```

And the errors:

> Can be used only in preamble... \newtheorem Environment thm
>   undefined... \begin{thm} \begin{document} ended by \end{thm}..
>   \end{thm}

Comment: Your code builds fine for me with no problem. How are you compiling your TeX file?

Comment: In any case, try moving the `\newtheorem` declaration to **before** the `\begin{document}` command. That is pretty much the solution to every "Can only be used in preamble" error.

Comment: I compile with PDFLatex

Comment: one `\newtheorem` i see is right after the `\documentclass` line.  it really should be input only *after* you load the desired theorem package.  (i see both `amsthm` and `theorem`, so there may conflicts from that.)  you've loaded packages more-or-less in alphabetical order, which is nice in some ways, but you do need to consider precedence -- `hyperref` should almost always be loaded last (exceptions are noted in package documentation).

Comment: This is not really an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). It should be as short as possible, without anything not relevant to your problem. Also, it doesn't replicate the problem you describe.

Comment: Barbara, I fix what you talk about, and nothing change.

Comment: Runar, I change the description of the problem, it's short.

Comment: Note that `hyperref` and `cleveref` should be loaded last, in this order.

Comment: Egreg, I loaded last, and nothing change.

Comment: Don't load `theorem`. [It is no longer suggested and its author recommends `amsthm` or `ntheorem` instead](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/theorem?lang=en). If you swap the order of `hyperref` and `cleveref` as egreg suggests (you still have them in the wrong order above), and remove `\usepackage{theorem}`, your file compiles file here.

Comment: Why do you load so many theorem-related packages? Removing `amsthm` solves the problem here, but you should probably remove `theorem` as well. `amsmath` is likely to be enough. Also, if you want somebody's attention in the comments, add a `@` in front of their name.

Comment: @RunarTrollet `amsmath` and `amsthm` do very different things.